# Pushing changes to a remote server from a locally started repo

Tags: git, version-control

I started a new project and created a local git repo with "git init" and now I have a few branches and everything works great.

However, since my webhosting company offers git hosting ([details](https://support.eapps.com/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=203) if you're curious), I'd like to push my entire repo to their servers to have a backup in the cloud in case something bad happens to my local repo.

How can I make the remote repo the "origin" since the repo was started locally?

Comment: Thanks for all your answers I had a problem making it work and it was because I initialized my remote repo with `git init` instead of `git init --bare`

Comment: After that I was able to do the following locally:

    cd /my/localRepo
    git remote add origin ssh://user@domain/path/to/repo
    git push origin master

After that I tested that everything was ok by deleting my local repo and executing:

    git clone ssh://user@domain/path/to/repo

Answer (score 6):

Do this:

```
git remote add origin <url of remote>
```

The url is the same you'd use to push, perhaps something like "ssh://user@host/path/to/repo.git"

You can go look at .git/config to see what it's set up there, if you like.

You may also want to add under `[branch "master"]` in .git/config (add the section if it's not there):

```
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

to tell git to associate your master and the remote master branch, so that when you just type "git pull" or "git push" with master checked out, it'll assume you meant origin's master.

This could also be done with the pair of commands:

```
git config branch.master.remote origin
git config branch.master.merge refs/heads/master
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`git remote`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html):

```
git remote add origin http://your.push.url
```

The first time you push, you will have to name the branch:

```
git push origin master
```

Subsequently, you can just:

```
git push
```

since `origin` is the default. To push other branches, see the [`git push`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html) documentation.

Comment: Are you saying that `git push <remote> <branch>` on a branch with no configured remote will automatically configure that remote/branch as default?

Comment: @Jefromi: Not quite, `git push` with no named remote defaults to `origin`, so you have to manually push your branch to `origin` first. If you used another remote name like `github`, then you would have to use `git push github` instead.

Comment: Oh, the push will work, right. But a pull won't without the configuration.

Comment: @GregHewgill Is that possible to remove local repository from scenario, and commit changes to remote repository directly?

Comment: @Mr.Hyde: No, there isn't. The way Git works requires you to commit the changes locally, then push them to a remote repository.

Comment: @GregHewgill What about this request in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38291364/controlling-git-repository-remotely

Answer (score 2):

If you started you repo locally, then you have no origin defined and `git remote` should produce no output. So you just need to define the new origin with, for example:

```
git remote add origin url
```