# Controlling git repository remotely

Tags: windows, git, version-control, sourcetree

My local git repository is on a Linux, on a vmware.
I want to know which file had been modified (Or which file is new), and controlling these events through GUI-tools.

Something like this:
[image]

I did it before using TortoiseSVN, this is working if my repository and GUI-tools be on same OS, but now my repository is on Linux and I need some GUI-tools on my windows to control the repository

**PS:** I don't want to make a copy of the repository on the windows, and sync both repositories.

Comment: Are you able to access the directories from Windows, ignoring Git for a moment? If not, then that's something that you'd need to solve first, and that doesn't have anything to do with Git.

Comment: @hvd Yes, I can. for example I'm currently access to directories and files through SSH protocol (using WinSCP tools) .

Comment: Okay, so you're not able to access them in standard applications, you need special tools to access files over SSH. That makes things more difficult, as Git is not a special tool to access files over SSH.

Comment: @hvd What do you mean by 'in standard applications' ? I'm owner of both servers. And I just tell my current situation to you. If there is another protocols and solutions, glad to hear that.

Comment: I mean you can't, for instance, run Notepad and edit a file directly on your Linux VM, as Notepad has not been designed to access files over SSH. And for remotely managing your Git repository, you probably would need to have such access that applications can access those files remotely without any support in the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use any GUI which uses git commandline (which is NOT TortoiseGit, but for example gitextensions, sourcetree, gitgui&gitk) and make it use instead of real Git a script which transparently runs each command at the remote system.

https://github.com/ericpruitt/sshfsexec is an example of such approach.

Comment: I didn't get it. Your given link is a script! But I'm familiar with SourceTree. How can I do that in this software?

Answer (score -1):

try Git-extension.
With this tool you can control everything just like you are using git shell.
see more @:
https://git-extensions-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: It's not magic. It can't show logs, create new commits, etc. without cloning first, and the OP for some reason doesn't want to clone.